# Time to create Spark jobs very long with many filter conditions on a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with shape `(1e10, 14)` and I'd like to filter it with about 50 compound OR statements, i.e.:

```
sql_string = "
(col1='val1' and col2=5) or 
(col1='val2' and col2=7) or
(col1='val3' and col2=5) or
...
"
df_f = df.filter(sql_string)
df_f.limit(1000).show()
```

If the number of these single OR statements is < 10, Spark Jobs for the show method are created instantaneously.
However, with about 15 ORs, it already takes about 30 seconds to create the Spark Jobs.
And at around 20 ORs, the time to create any Spark Jobs grows unmanageable (more than hours).

Starting with about 15 ORs, GC Allocation messages are displayed every few seconds, i.e.:

```
2020-05-04T09:55:50.762+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 7015644K->1788K(7016448K)] 7266861K->253045K(21054976K), 0.0063209 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

So it seems like something funky is going on. Feels similar to the issue, when one loops over Spark Dataframes?

The driver has 32GB RAM (10G used) and 4 cores (1 core 100% used, others near 0%). 
I/O is pretty much zero.
Though there is 100% usage on one core, the cluster thinks it's inactive, since it shuts down after the inactivity time that I've set.

Here is a link to the execution plan: https://pastebin.com/7MEv5Sq2.

Comment: If possible try caching the dataframe before running the filter query.

Comment: Indeed, caching the df before filtering brings the Job Creation time back to instant. Why is this the case?
However, for the 1e10 dataset mentioned here is part of a factor 1e3 larger dataset, so it's not feasible to cache in memory anymore. I could only persist it on disk, but I guess that the same problem occurs then.

Comment: ORC file format from what I can see?

Comment: driver is not really the issue here.

Comment: I assume the job finishes though. How are you running?

Comment: I am not sure I get you. ORC files with pushdown means most of work occurring with ORC engine. Show will be for Driver

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, you are filtering the dataframe based on multiple hardcoded values using compound OR statements, so the spark catalyst optimizer also have to check each filter one by one and loading the complete dataframe after every OR statement is executed.

So, when we cache the dataframe it already have it in memory hence executing it faster by passing the cached dataframe to all the executors.

For large dataframes, you can try persist on mem and disk, that should give you the performance boost you seek but if that doesn't work, you can improve your query by filtering the dataframe by col1 then filtering the already filtered dataframe on col2. This will require you to implement a little logic based approach in order to minimize the iterations over large data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! What is confusing me though, is that no spark jobs are created without caching. I.e. the executors are not even used. So it cannot be related due to the caching of the executors I guess?
I also just tried it with the larger dataset, shape(>1e13, 14), and it still works - no OOM error, though the large dataset cannot fit into the RAM.

Comment: so u r saying that wholestagecodegen cannot optimize an or statement and will re-read?

Comment: @thebluephantom Not exactly re-read. Looking at the optimized logical plan in the question it doesn't look better, the wholestagecodegen converts multiple operators into one single java function but if you are having hardcoded values to filter the dataframe the number of iterations are still going to be the same. I am open if you can provide a better explanation.

Comment: Right, it is an ORC file u r reading. ORC is columnar. I suspect that it means the columns asre being scanned with the ((((.

Answer (score 1):

Being originally from Cloudera stack experience, I tended to work with parquet & kudu.

None-the-less the following even though not sure what you are asking in reality, seems more like observations:

1. 50 filters takes time, no filter is at the other end of the spectrum, but takes obviously near to zero processing time in that context. OR processing is more expensive.
2. push-down is evident from physical plan and is now Spark default for ORC processing.
3. ORC engine does push down work, hence far less executor activity you observe.
4. limit cannot be pushed down to database or parquet / orc.
5. GC stuff can be ignored.

My overall take: With a 1e10 vertical shape element, nothing unusual in my view.

First posted answer not correct.

Comment: Thank you! Just for clarification, the cache() did work though. Without caching, no Spark Jobs are created, and I just get the GC messages, till I get kicked of the cluster due to inactivity (1hr). Ganglia shows 1 core 100% CPU usage and 10G RAM though. With caching (and no GC messages), a few Spark Jobs are created and the show() with limit 1000 is done in about a minute. So something strange is definitely going on.

Comment: I noted there was an issue (in the past) with limit meaning less parallelization. DFs seem to work differently with Job kickoff. I tested your stuff without .cache and it ran as well, interesting. Spark 2.4.5

Comment: I'm also running 2.4.5 (on Databricks DBR 6.4). However, I guess there are many subjects possibly playing a role, i.e. data storage (in my case via Azure), cluster setup, maybe still file format etc.. Nevertheless, it's good to know that this should in general also work fine without caching!